# Parallelogram OPQR is such that OP=[-7,24] and OR=[-8,-1] determine the acute angle between the diagonals OQ and RP.

Tags: geometry, vectors, angle

I'm just really stuck on this question I only found the magnitude of OP = 25 and RP=√65

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Determine the vectors representing OQ and RP, then take the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of them using the $2$ different standard definitions (with one involving the angle between the vectors), and then compare these $2$ results. I trust you can finish the rest yourself.